# The code in the Ajax done method doesn't recognize the code thats already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am trying to make a dynamic system where a button changes when you click on another button. For instance, when you click on the button: "12+4", different buttons will appear at another div. I use an append method for that. But when you click on one of the "patroon" buttons, it will not execute the `$(".tile").on('click', function)`. That is because that code is already executed before the ajax call. My code is below:

```
        arr.forEach(function (value, key) {
           $("#row2").append('<button class="dikte" data-value="' + key + '">' + value + '</button>')
        });

        $(".dikte").on('click', function () {
            let dataVal = $(this).data('value');

            // Code...
            $.ajax({
                url: "Api/getObjectGroepen.php",
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    // $(".spinner-border").removeClass("d-none");
                },
                success: function () {
                    // $(".spinner-border").addClass("d-none");
                }
            }).done(function (data) {
                $("#row3").html("");
                $(arrObjectGroep).each(function (key, value) {
                    $("#row3").append('<button class="btn tile" data-value="' + value + '">' + JSON.parse(data)[value] + '</button>')
                });
            });
        });

        // Tile section
        $(".tile").on("click", function (e) {
            // Prevents button from executing
            e.preventDefault();
            // execute code
            console.log(123);
        });
```

So the `$(".tile")` are all the buttons. And `$(".dikte")` is the "12+4" button.

Hopefully someone understands my problem about what is going on, it's maybe a bit hard to explain, but I can explain further if there are any questions. Is there a clean and simple solution for this? Rather than moving all the code to the done method.

Comment: Hi you mean  $(".tile").on('click', function) event is not triggering ?

Comment: Yes indeed, on the                     $("#row3").append('<button class="btn tile" data-value="' + value + '">' + JSON.parse(data)[value] + '</button>')

Comment: Hi i have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery doesn't know the button's which you appended dynamically, for that your code should be like below, and which will rescan the document to find the element with the class name

```
$(document).on('click','.tile',function(e){
    // code
});
```

Comment: Wow that's exactly what I needed! Thanks!